# How to layer graphics in java?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am trying to make my own version of checkers and I have currently written the code to store draw the board and the pieces.

Every time I run the code I get a different result because the board is being drawn over some pieces. How do I get all the pieces to appear over the board all the time? I understand similar questions have been asked but they don't provide any useful help.

Here's the code that is draws the board:

```
public void paint(Graphics gr) {
    Graphics2D gr2D = (Graphics2D) gr;
    gr2D.setColor(color1);
    BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(strokeThickness,
            BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
    gr2D.setStroke(stroke);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            gr.setColor((gr.getColor() == color2)
                    ? color1 : color2);
            gr.fillRect((int) (start + CHANGEVAL * i),
                    (int) (start + CHANGEVAL * j),
                    (int) CHANGEVAL,
                    (int) CHANGEVAL);
        }
        gr.setColor((gr.getColor() == color2)
                ? color1 : color2);
    }
}
```

And here's the code that draws the pieces:

```
public static void setPieces() {
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            aryPiecePos[posX][posY] = SQUARE_STATE_RED;
            board.repaint(board.getCoordX(posX), board.getCoordY(posY), Color.RED);
            posX += 2;
        }
        posX = (posX == 8 ? 1 : 0);
        posY += 1;
    }
    posX = 1;
    posY = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            aryPiecePos[posX][posY] = SQUARE_STATE_BLACK;
            board.repaint(board.getCoordX(posX), board.getCoordY(posY), Color.BLACK);
            posX += 2;
        }
        posX = (posX == 8 ? 1 : 0);
        posY += 1;
    }
}
```

Also here's a link to all my code: 
Here's a hyperlink to what I have currently: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2uJqRSB8ckHYW53NmZsZDdxWWs

Answer (score 0):

What you draw first will be in a deeper layer so to speak.

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
```

With the above code the blue rectangle will not be visible, since the green one is drawn over it.

**Therefore to solve your problem you need to draw the board first, then all the pieces.**